# Wine is still available after uninstalling it

Tags: centos, yum, rpm, wine

I am facing a problem that I don't understand on a CentOS 7.4 box.

Someone installed a wine and didn't documented how they installed it (was it with `yum`, directly with a `rpm` or built from sources? I don't know). Now I need to uninstall it, so I did the following:

- I used `sudo yum remove wine*` which uninstalled about 15 different packages
- Using `rpm -qa | grep wine` I checked that the previous packages are indeed uninstalled.

The problem is that I still have a wine executable when I do `which wine` I get `/usr/local/bin/wine` and `ls -l /usr/local/bin/ | grep wine` returns

```
-rwxr-xr-x  1 root root   17616  wine
-rwxr-xr-x  1 root root    1973  wineboot
-rwxr-xr-x  1 root root  247924  winebuild
-rwxr-xr-x  1 root root    1973  winecfg
-rwxr-xr-x  1 root root    1973  wineconsole
lrwxrwxrwx  1 root root       7  winecpp -> winegcc
-rwxr-xr-x  1 root root    1973  winedbg
-rwxr-xr-x  1 root root  413540  winedump
-rwxr-xr-x  1 root root    1973  winefile
lrwxrwxrwx  1 root root       7  wineg++ -> winegcc
-rwxr-xr-x  1 root root   72700  winegcc
-rwxr-xr-x  1 root root   95099  winemaker
-rwxr-xr-x  1 root root    1973  winemine
-rwxr-xr-x  1 root root    1973  winepath
-rwxr-xr-x  1 root root   32256  wine-preloader
-rwxr-xr-x  1 root root 2821988  wineserver
```

So I had the idea to remove these files (I moved them actually) but then when I use the command wine instead of having the expected `not a command` error message I get `/usr/local/bin/wine: No such file or directory` which makes me think that the uninstallation wasn't performed completely. (So for now I moved back my files to `/usr/local/bin`)

Hence my questions:

- What is keeping a reference to `/usr/local/bin/wine` and why does it keep this reference? (Note that `alternatives --list | grep wine` returns nothing)
- How do I get rid of this wine installation completely and in a clean way?

---

**Edit** I have to add that `sudo yum erase wine* --remove-leaves` returns `Command line error: no such option: --remove-leaves`.

```
[user@host]$ yum --version
3.4.3
  Installed: rpm-4.11.3-32.el7.x86_64 at 2018-05-04 08:10
  Built    : Red Hat, Inc. <http://bugzilla.redhat.com/bugzilla> at 2017-11-13 15:51
  Committed: Panu Matilainen <pmatilai@redhat.com> at 2017-11-13

  Installed: yum-3.4.3-154.el7.noarch at 2018-04-06 13:07
  Built    : Red Hat, Inc. <http://bugzilla.redhat.com/bugzilla> at 2017-03-27 16:30
  Committed: Valentina Mukhamedzhanova <vmukhame@redhat.com> at 2017-03-27
```

Comment: https://forums.fedoraforum.org/showthread.php?163598-HOW-do-I-uninstall-wine-completely

Answer (score 5, accepted):

When you moved `/usr/local/bin/wine*` away, your shell still remembered the commands you’d run previously; after moving files in your path, you need to run

```
hash -r
```

to force the shell to rediscover what executables are available when you try to run them.

To cleanly remove Wine, you’d really need to know how it was installed. In your case, I think the best you can do is to remove all the Wine executables in `/usr/local/bin` (`wine*`, `regedit`, `regsrv32`, `msiexec`), and remove its associated directories, `/usr/local/lib/wine` and `/usr/local/share/wine` (or something similar). You’ll probably want to look for Wine prefixes, and remove those too; `find / -type d -name drive_c -printf %p\\n` will list those for you.

Comment: Thank you for your explanation, I feel better now that I understand why the executable was still referenced (reading `man hash` was helpful). I will follow your advice and just delete the remaining executables.